# XCode6/Swift/CoreData, same model on both Mac and iOS project

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, core-data, swift

I am playing last few weeks with Swift and CoreData on both Mac and iOS.

Model which I use is originally created in project for iOS. I have successfully created Objective-C NSManagedObject classes and inserting, fetching records work perfect.

Then, I have drag and drop model file from iOS project to Mac (OS X) project. I have checked all properties and it seems that he copied it well. I have again created Objective-C NSManagedObject classes, xCode done a bridging and that's fine. I am even able to insert new entities without any problems, but with fetching - there are problems:

I am using following code for fetching records into array:

```
var recipesArray: Recipe[] {
get {
    if !_recipesArray {
        var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Recipe")

        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "title", ascending: true)

        request.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

        var fetchResults = appDelegate.managedObjectContext?.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)

        if (!fetchResults) {
            println("fetch error")
        }

        println(fetchResults)

        _recipesArray = fetchResults as? Recipe[]

    }
    return _recipesArray!;
}
}
```

This is same code as I use in iOS project, but won't work. When I use debugger tool-tips, or prinln I get correct number of records, but for each record (entity) I get following error:

```
[0] = <error: use of undeclared identifier 'cocoarr'
error: 1 errors parsing expression
```

I am not sure if I do anything wrong. Maybe I have missed some important step, or there are some limitations which I need to consider.

I like to notify that I have checked both .sqlite files in SQLite client and there are some differences between iOS and OS X file. Tried to go trough xCode generated CoreData code in AppDelegate file and it seems that same parameters are used when stores are created.

Thank you very much for any help.